# Apache mod_rewrite logging

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I can't get `mod_rewrite` to log anything about what it's doing. You can imagine that this makes debugging `mod_rewrite`... challenging. I've followed the "instructions" at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html (I'm running 2.2.22 on a Mac), except that they're missing critical details like... which of the config files to put the configuration in, and in which level of XML elements.

```
RewriteLog "/tmp/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 8
```

Where do I put these directives so that I actually get logging about what `mod_rewrite` is doing? `/tmp/rewrite.log` is created, so Apache has some clue about what I want, but it logs nothing at all to this file.